# How to run application on port 3000 on Public and Not Private IP Address in AWS EC2 Instance (so it can be accessed on the internet)

Tags: amazon-ec2

My problem is that I want to run an application on an AWS EC2 instance on port 3000. I then want to be able to access it from the internet using http:/PUBLIC_IP:3000. The problem is that when I am running the application on the EC2 instance, it runs on the private IP - and therefore I cant access it from the internet. How would I make sure that the app will run on the public ip, or how would I set it up, so I can access the application over the internet?

I tried to find a solution online, but some hours later I find myself in here.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify - are you looking for a way to add a public IP to an instance that only has a private IP, or does your instance already have a public IP and you can't access your application through it? Also how are you checking the connectivity over private IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. It was very helpful in debugging the error. It turned out that the security group of the EC2 instance was not allowing traffic on port 3000 so I had to add that - and then it worked.

I furthermore had trouble putting it behind a Load Balancer. The solution to that was that it was a webpack application and in .webpack there is a configuration file where you can add e.g., allowedHosts: [.amazonaws.com].